# How many ways the number $n$ can be written as a product?

Tags: combinatorics, products

How many ways the number $n$ can be written as a product?

I am only looking for the growth rate of the function. Is this an exponential function (after the number of digits $n$)?

Number $1$ can not be used. The number of factors can be completely arbitrary. We include only positive integers.

Comment: You should perhaps be more specific about what would be allowable as a product?  (Two factors? More than two factors? Does changing the order of the factors count? Can $1$ be used as a factor?, etc.)

Comment: This is very unclear.  What counts as "different ways?"  Is $1\times 1 \times 1 \times n$ different from $n \times 1^8$?  If $n = 24$, is $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 8 \cdot 3 = 3 \cdot 8 =  2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 3^{-1]\cdot 2 \cdot 3^{2} \cdot 2^2$?

Comment: No, $1$ can not be used. The number of factors can be completely arbitrary. We include only positive integers.

Comment: How many ways for any prime number?  Prime numbers can be huge.

Comment: Yes - for any..

Comment: Do you count $2\cdot 4$ as the same as $4\cdot 2$?

Comment: $(\zeta(s) -1)^k$ is the (dirichlet) generating function with coefficients $a_n$ the number of ordered factorisations of $n$ into $k$ factors if we exclude 1. So you are I guess interested in the coefficients of $\frac{1}{2-\zeta(k)}$ ? If so you're probably in luck, if you don't care about order, don't know.

Comment: Yes it is the same ($2 \cdot 4$ and $4 \cdot 2$). I forgot to mention it. However, the solution for the opposite condition is also nice to see.

Comment: you should edit your question to include your clarification

Comment: "How many ways the number n can be written as a product?" and "The number of factors can be completely arbitrary"  Huh?  Obviously the number of ways is completely determined by the number of factors. "Is this an exponential function".  That seems logical.  As numbers get larger primes get scarce and numbers will have (on average) more factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume we don't care about the order of the factors.

---

Let's look at an example:

*what are the factorisations of 36?*

*Answer*
\begin{array}{|c|r|}\hline
\text{$1$ part} & 36\\\hline
\text{$2$ parts} & 2\cdot 18,\, 3\cdot 12,\, 4\cdot 9,\, 6\cdot 6\\\hline
\text{$3$ parts} & 2\cdot 2\cdot 9,\, 2\cdot 3\cdot 6,\, 3\cdot 3\cdot 4\\\hline
\text{$4$ parts} & 2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 3\\\hline\end{array}

---

Using the form of the factorisations as a model we can see that a general factorisation of a number $n$ is of the form $2^{k_2}\cdot 3^{k_3}\cdot 4^{k_4}\cdots$. This suggests a dirichlet generating function (*dgf*)

$$\begin{align}g(z)=&(2^{-0z}+2^{-1z}+2^{-2z}+\cdots)\times\\&(3^{-0z}+3^{-1z}+3^{-2z}+\cdots)\times (4^{-0z}+4^{-1z}+4^{-2z}+\cdots)\cdots\, .\end{align}$$

Or, since $1/(1-u)=u^0+u^1+u^2+\cdots$, we have:

$$g(z)=\prod_{r=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-r^{-z}}\, .\tag{1}$$

The coefficient of $n^{-z}$ is the number of factorisions of $n$.

If we are interested in the number of parts then we can tag each factor with the variable $y$ to give the $2$-variable dirichlet/ordinary generating function

$$f(y,z)=\prod_{r=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-yr^{-z}}\, .\tag{2}$$

So, the coefficient of $n^{-z}y^p$ in $(2)$ is the number of factorisions of $n$ into $p$ parts.

I'm not sure about growth rates but for more on $(1)$ see this [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition) or the [oeis sequence A001055](https://oeis.org/A001055).

Answer (score 0):

*This is only a partial answer*:

If I understand your question correctly, $p^5$, where $p$ is a prime, can be factored as: $$\begin{align}p^5\tag{1}\\p\times p^4\tag{2}\\p^2\times p^3\tag{3}\\p\times p\times p^3\tag{4}\\p\times p^2\times p^2\tag{5}\\p\times p\times p\times p^2\tag{6}\\p\times p\times p\times p\times p\tag{7}\end{align}$$

This is equivalent to solving $$p^{a_1}\times p^{a_2}\times p^{a_3}\times p^{a_4}\times p^{a_5}=p^5$$ or $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=5$$ with the condition that $0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3\leq a_4\leq a_5$ (this will ensure that the order doesn't matter). The solution to the above equation is known as the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), which I will denote by $\rho$ to distinguish it from $p$ (indeed $\rho(5)=7$ from the example with $n=p^5$).

More generally for $n=p^k$ we need to solve $$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k=k$$ with the condition $0\leq a_1\leq a_2\leq\dots\leq a_k$, and here the number of solutions is $\rho(k)$.

There is no known closed form for $\rho(k)$ as far as I know.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, this is incorrect. For example $n=6$ can be factorised as $6$ or $2\cdot 3$, so $2$ ways, but $6=2^1\cdot 3^1$ and $\rho(1)\cdot\rho(1)=1$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain You're right, I noticed that too and edited my answer.